# Character and centralizer of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to solve the exercise 2.15 from Isaacs Character Theory.

Let $\chi\in Irr(G)$ be faithful and let $H$ be a non-trivial proper subgroup of $G$ such that $\chi_{H} \in Irr(H)$. Show that $C_{G}(H)=Z(G)$

Obviously $Z(G)\le C_G(H)$ and so it suffices to show that $C_G(H)\le Z(G)$.

What I got sofar: Since $\chi$ is irreducible and faithful, $Z(\chi)=Z(G)$.  By the same reasoning, $Z(\chi_H)=Z(H)$ and so $Z(H)=Z(\chi_H)=H\cap Z(\chi)=H\cap Z(G)$.

Comment: By Schur's Lemma, the image of $C_G(H)$ in the representation corresponding to $\chi$ consists of scalar matrices.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{X}:G \leftarrow Gl(V)$ be a representation affording $\chi$. Let $x\in C_G(H)$. Then for every $h\in H, \mathfrak{X}(x) \mathfrak{X}(h)=\mathfrak{X}(h)\mathfrak{X}(x)$. If I set $f=\mathfrak{X}$, then I have $f\mathfrak{X}(x)=\mathfrak{X}(x)f$ with $\mathfrak{X}$ irreducible. By Schur's lemma, $f$ is an homothety. Thanks Derek.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant $f\mathfrak{X}_H=\mathfrak{X}_Hf$ with $\mathfrak{X}_H$ irreducible.